# Second monitor in dual setup (windows 10) keeps pushing windows onto primary, how do I make this stop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup, my laptop (Dell XPS 13) is my primary and I have an Acer monitor as my secondary. I'm currently using a VGA DisplayLink adapter to connect my two screens.

After a while of having a window (like Google Chrome) open on the Acer monitor, both of my screens go black before turning back on and all of the windows I had open appear on my laptop screen instead of where it was. This happens even when I don't have a window open to full screen on the secondary and when my laptop is actively being used and did not go to sleep. It happens especially quickly when I am trying to watch anything full screen on the secondary monitor.

I have updated all the drivers for both my laptop and the monitor and don't know what else to do. Please help! It's been very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Both screen going black is an indication to me of a graphics driver issue. I know you said you updated, but you may be able to get a newer version directly from Intel (or Nvidia) rather than Dell. Why don't you post more info about your graphics card, driver version, & info on the DisplayLink to VGA adapter. That also could require a driver and/or firmware update.

How often does the both screens going black happen? Does it happen if you aren't using the DisplayLink adapter (to isolate if that is possibly causing)?